# Electrolytic reduction of nitrobenzene in differing media

Tags: electrochemistry, aromatic-compounds, organic-reduction, nitro-compounds, rearrangements

In my lecture notes it is given that in a weakly acidic medium, nitrobenzene on electrolytic reduction gives aniline, which makes sense to me because there is ample H+ in the medium to continue adding electrons and H+ to fully reduce nitrobenzene past nitrosobenzene and phenyl hydroxylamine to aniline.

However, in strongly acidic medium electrolysis apparently gives p-aminophenol via rearrangement of the hydroxyl-amine.

Google only showed me this result, and I couldn't find any convincing reason for this.

- Why does the reduction not go all the way to aniline?
- Why does this rearrangement take place and why is it favored by strongly acidic media?